# TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined gm library

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, gm

Previously, I had followed this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) to successfully create thumbnail images using AWS Lambda. The node version was **8.10**.

Now, as AWS will be deprecating any application with this node version, i have to update the node version to **10.x**.

> We are contacting you as we have identified that your AWS Account
>   currently has one or more Lambda functions using Node.js 8.10, which
>   will reach its EOL at the end of 2019.
>
> What’s happening?
>
> The Node community has decided to end support for Node.js 8.x on
>   December 31, 2019 [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). From this date forward, Node.js 8.x will stop
>   receiving bug fixes, security updates, and/or performance
>   improvements. To ensure that your new and existing functions run on a
>   supported and secure runtime, language runtimes that have reached
>   their EOL are deprecated in AWS [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCCTa.png).
>
> For Node.js 8.x, there will be 2 stages to the runtime deprecation
>   process:
>
> 1. Disable Function Create – Beginning January 6, 2020, customers will no longer be able to create functions using Node.js 8.10
> 2. Disable Function Update – Beginning February 3, 2020, customers will no longer be able to update functions using Node.js 8.10
>
> After this period, both function creation and updates will be disabled
>   permanently. However, existing Node 8.x functions will still be
>   available to process invocation events.
>
> What do I need to do?
>
> We encourage you to update all of your Node.js 8.10 functions to the
>   newer available runtime version, Node.js 10.x[3]. You should test your
>   functions for compatibility with the Node.js 10.x language version
>   before applying changes to your production functions.
>
> What if I have issues/What if I need help?
>
> Please contact us through AWS Support [4] or the AWS Developer Forums
>   [5] should you have any questions or concerns.

So, i have updated my node version to **10.17.0** and deploy the package again in AWS Lambda. Now, if any image has been uploaded to S3 and aws lambda tries to convert the image into a thumbnail, it shows below error:

[image]

This is the full code:

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1].toLowerCase();
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback(`Unsupported image type: ${imageType}`);
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

The error is basically in this line:

```
gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width, // In this line where the size is undefined
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
```

The node version of 8.10 is working perfectly. I have no clue what to do in this case. I have the memory size of **1024MB** in the configuration

Can anyone point me out on where should i change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that gm is not supported anymore with NodeJS 10.x: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/752.

So there will be problems here. It seems like you have to create and use a Lambda layer to fix it. But the real problem occurs, if you are using Lambda@Edge, since Lambda layers are not allowed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html

Comment: Just to complete the answer: You should use Sharp now for image manipulation.